# Why is SQL Server Express creating twenty users on my system?

Tags: security, sql-server-express

I was taking a look into Computer Management->Users and found that SQL Server Express has created a lot of users for me.

Why? Is my system infected?

[image: local users]

The descriptions all say, "Local user account for execution of R scripts in SQL Server instance SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: Please take some time and go through your questions and mark the helpful answers as a courtesy to the people helping you.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have installed the R- and Machine Learning services? According to the documentation below those are generated to run external scripts of those services in an isolated environment. So I would say they are normal if you install those components.

Those are part of the Advanced Services Variant of the SQL Express Edition.

From the documentation: [Modify the user account pool for SQL Server machine learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/modify-the-user-account-pool-for-sql-server-r-services)

> By default, the user account pool contains 20 user accounts. In most cases, 20 is more than adequate to support machine learning tasks, but you can change the number of accounts.
>
> - In a default instance, the individual accounts are named **MSSQLSERVER01** through **MSSQLSERVER20**.
> - For a named instance, the individual accounts are named after the instance name: for example, **MyInstanceName01** through **MyInstanceName20**.

Comment: Sadly the link now leads to a 404 :( Anyway, to change the user account pool run "SQL Server configuration manager", right click on "SQL Server Launchpad" -> Properties -> Advanced -> External Users Count

Answer (score 2):

Open `Windows Security log` and filter it for `Event ID 4720`: A user account was created.

You'll found who, when and with what attributes has created these users.

Comment: It got an empty list, opening event viewer, went into "Windows Logs" and "Security", then I right clicked "Security" and clicked "Filter Current Log"... and put 4720 in the  textbox saying `<All Event IDs>`.

Comment: It is. It enabled by default, but if it is I bet it would say ‚TRUSTED INSTALLER‘ ,)